# Sound - SOX: How can I make a 180 degrees phase shifted version of an audio file/ stream?

Tags: audio, command-line-interface, sox

I'm trying to get a 180 degrees phase shifted waves that effectively cancels the sound if mixed with or played in sync with?

Please limit the answers to sox, the 'Swiss Army knife of sound processing programs'.

Comment: It is very likely you asked in the wrong place; I'd suggest you to try asking on SuperUser.com for this.

Comment: I checked. There's a number of sox-related questions in here, thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the -v option combined with a negative value. Using -1 you'll get a new signal you are looking for.

As an example, you could synthesize a cosine signal:

```
sox -n cos.wav synth 3 sine 500
```

and then change its phase using the -v option:

```
sox -v -1 cos.wav sin.wav
```

If you then combine the 2 signal together

```
sox -m cos.wav sin.wav sum.wav
```

you'll see you have obtained a null signal

Comment: Your examples work perfectly, thank you. However I'm trying to apply this in realtime to whatever my laptop mic picks up and I'm hearing on my headset. I'm basically trying to apply this to the live output of this command:

'sox --buffer 1024 -d -d'

Comment: Minor issue here: the naming of sin.wav and cos.wav signals is semantically wrong, the first sox command generates a sine (3 seconds 500Hz) and not a cosine.
The second generates an inverted sine and not a sine phase shifted from a cos which would mean 90 degrees phase shift.